# How to use \ContinuedFloat with figure side by side together?

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I want to plot a subfigure `side by side` using `\ContinuedFloat` as shown below:

[image]

However, I always get below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hb!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 1}
        \label{fig:arm1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 2}
        \label{fig:arm2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.6\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 3}
        \label{fig:arm2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{$Q^{*}$ values for different arms}
\end{figure}%

\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} %
        \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 4}
        \label{fig:arm3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} %
        \subcaption{$Q^{*}$ values for arm 5}
        \label{fig:arm4}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{$Q^{*}$ values for different arms (cont.)}
    \label{fig:arms}
\end{figure}






\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}






    \end{document}
```

Comment: Assuming that you are fine with figure a-c being displayed below each other, while you want image d and e to show side by side, just remove all the empty lines between the two corresponding subfigure environments.

Comment: @leandriis. Sorry, not sure if I get your meaning. The `the all the empty lines between the two corresponding subfigure`. But there is no line between the subfigure

Comment: There is an empty line between `\end{subfigure}` and `\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}` in the second `figure` environment. Remove or comment out this empty line and your images should show up side by side.

Comment: @leandriis. Thanks a lot! Brillant! It works. I feel very strange `an empty` line will give a huge different.